# DAPP toolchains

Tags: dapp-development, mix

So Mix, being the dog it is, [ate my homework](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/521), yet I really like the offline chain integration of the IDE.

How are other people setting up their dev toolchains?